# Почему не отправляется форма

Tags: php, html, форма

Использую phpmailer

html:

```
<form action="block/mail.php" method="post">
    <div class="inputs">
        <ul>
            <li>Фамилия:<br><input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"></li>
            <li">Имя:<br><input type="text" id="first_name"></li>
            <li>Телефон:<br><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"></li>
            <li">E-mail:<br><input type="text" id="email" name="email"></li>
            <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = 'test@test.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Testname';
$mail->AddAddress('test2@test.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Body = "Name: $lname";

$mail->Send();
?>
```

Comment: Данные формы не отправляются или почта? Если почтовое сообщение, то как вы это определили? Ошибку выводит? Тестировали на реальном хостинге или на локальном? Если второе, то проверяли соответствующую папку, куда должны складироваться письма после эмуляции отправки?

Comment: А отправляется с localhost небось? И все на Windows? Ну, так нужно же правильно сконфигурировать.

Comment: На локальном, ошибок нет, в папке пусто.
Если просто выполнить php письмо приходит

Comment: Скоро начну на такого типа вопросы писать много нехороших слов и минусы ставить. Где проверяете (хостинг? локалка?) sendmail настроен? выдает ошибки? какие? Не показывайте нам, что вы списали пример, а он не работает. Рассказывайте, что пытались сделать и что   при этом получилось. Думаю так вы ответы быстрее получите.

Comment: Ошибок вообще нет, все настроено и работает, но только не отправляет кнопкой

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше и от себя могу добавить, что бы проверить, отправляется ли вообще что-то с формы - после приёма данных в переменную сразу выведите её значение на экран **Echo "$lname";** и если ничего не выводит, значит ничего не отправляется или же отправляются пустые значения //У меня был похожий случай, хром отправлял данные, а мозилла отправляла пустые поля//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не указан атрибут **method** в форме? Вы ж наверно проверяете - пришли данные или нет? По умолчанию (без его указания), у вас отправляется методом GET, а вы принимаете, как POST

---

И еще, проверил ваш код, сделав одно единственное изменение: **method="post"**. Всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо всем, проблема в action="block/mail.php"
Как указать адрес правильно?

Comment: @moserevg, вы имеете в виду, что путь указали не верно? Или про какой адрес идёт речь?

Comment: Я уже сам запутался. У меня форма во всплывающем блоке, который изначально display=none и появляется посредством js. Почему то изза этого письмо и не шлется. Если сделать display=block, то все отлично

Comment: У вас папка "block" находиться в корне сайта? Если да, то попробуйте и путь указать от корня. Т.е в вашем случае, надо добавить в начало пути слеш: **action="/block/mail.php"**

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Решил переделать всплывающее окно

Comment: @Deonis или так:

> action="./block/mail.php"